# Nginx reverse-proxy pass front-end application matching url from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect, pattern-matching

I everyone. I'm very new to Nginx. My situation is like this.
I have a Php application which that handles both backend and front-end, and also I have another ReactJs application as a micro-frontend service. *I'm using a Docker container for the Nginx service*.

Currently, domains are like this;
Php application - `https://my.happy.customers.local`
ReactJs - `http://my.happy.customers.profile.local`

What I want to achieve here is, whenever customers when to `https://my.happy.customers.local/user/1234567989/profile` url I want to send users to `http:///my.happy.customers.profile.local:3001/user/1234567989/profile` url.

All the cookies and local-storage values are bound to the `https://my.happy.customers.local` domain, so I want to use them from the second domain too.

How can I do this??

I managed to redirect url but in that way, I'm losing all cookies.

```
location ~ ^/(user)(/.*)(/profile)(/.*) {
  rewrite ^/(user)(/.*)(/profile)(/.*)$ http:///my.happy.customers.profile.local:3001$request_uri redirect
}
```

If I can redirect the user to the micro-frontend without changing the url, it will be great. Is this possible?

I tried this way but it's giving me an error.

```
location ~ ^/(user)(/.*)(/profile)(/.*) {
      resolver my.happy.customers.profile.local;
      proxy_pass http://my.happy.customers.profile.local:3001$request_uri
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is the correct approach. However, there are issues in your example:

You have typed `localtion`, it should be `location`.

For the `resolver` directive, you need to specify either the domain name or IP address/addresses of the name servers you want nginx to use to resolve domain names. I doubt you have installed a recursive DNS resolver to `my.happy.customers.profile.local` server.